# Why were there only 2 guards for Hannibal Lecter on the 6th floor?

Tags: the-silence-of-the-lambs

The rest of the building was swarming with SWAT team guys and other very professional-looking guys, but they placed only two old men to guard Hannibal Lecter on the 6th floor. Which very conveniently allowed Hannibal to slip out (admittedly with a little bit of ingenuity and work).

Is there any rational, plausible in-universe explanation for this poor security arrangement?

Comment: They weren't old men: "Officers Pembry and Boyle were experienced men brought especially from Brushy Mountain State
Prison to be Dr. Lecter’s warders."

Answer (score 3):

He was confined in a cage, and no one anticipated that he would have managed to smuggle in a pen clip and be able to remove his handcuffs. Under the circumstances, it seemed unlikely that he would be able to escape his cage or the building, and even if he did, the police no doubt that they could keep him from getting very far.

Comment: They did not anticipate that? Everything about the precautions that were instituted around him suggests the exact opposite. Everything except for the fact that they left him with only two guards in his immediate area; they did not even have CCTV. They clearly had no shortage of personnel who could have guarded him; the staging of only two guards was a clear plot hole designed to allow the Lecter character to escape.